# How to query all custom posts of a certain type and checking what category they have

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, loop

Here's what I have:

Custom Post type: Vendors

Vendor categories:

- Wedding
- Party
- Catering

I want to query all Vendors and then assign them a class based on the category they are in. The class would be .wedding if they are categorized as wedding and .party for party and so on.

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'vendors',
   'order' => 'asc',
   'orderby' => 'title',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

So that grabs the posts in order by title.  I want to add the class based off of their category and echo them as a list item as so:

```
<ul>
   <li class=".category">TITLE</li>
   <li class=".category">TITLE</li>
<ul>
```

I also want to query from the posts and categories that are made in Wordpress, not from some pre-defined list since this will be changing every now and then.  I know I'll want to do a foreach loop but I'm not sure how to find their taxonomy and echo it as a class.

Comment: In your list, is `TITLE` the category title or post title? Do you even need posts or just categories? Is there a specific class you want or do you want each category to have a unique class ( think slug ) ?

Comment: Title is the post title.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I figured it out!

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'vendors',
'order' => 'asc',
'orderby' => 'title',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();
    $category = get_the_category();
    echo '<li class="';
    echo $category[0]->category_nicename;
    echo '">' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer so we can get this one solved and closed. :-)